# Divide a number and each successive answer x times in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a vector that takes an input value (i.e: 128) and divides it and each successive answer by 2 for x amount of times.

In other words, I would like a simple function that takes an input of 128 and halves that a defined number of times. So for example

```
x = 128
someFunction(x/2, 12)
64 32 16 8 4 2 1 0.5 0.25 0.125 0.0625 0.03125
```

After scouring the internet for about an hour I can't figure out a way to do this without manually inputting the values. I'm sorry if this is a basic question, but there doesn't seem to be a simple way to get this done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f = function(x, n)
    x / 2^(1:n)

> f(128, 12)
 [1] 64.00000 32.00000 16.00000  8.00000  4.00000  2.00000  1.00000  0.50000
 [9]  0.25000  0.12500  0.06250  0.03125
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Apparently I need to go back to a remedial math course.